# HTML5 ContentEditable only when logged in

Tags: html, authentication, save, admin, contenteditable

I'm creating a very basic website for someone, and they only want to be able to edit certain attributes of the site, namely the body text. I figured that using ContentEditable would be the best solution for this, because WordPress or a similar CMS would be complete overkill for such a simple thing. Here is a list of what I'm looking for, and if anyone could help me it would be most appreciated!

1. Basic login form (only needs to have one user/password (for the admin)) on it's own page.
2. Once logged in, the admin can see a little "edit" icon/button that regular users can't see.
3. Clicking that will activate ContentEditable, and once finished editing, there will be a "save" button that will save the text back for everyone to see.

I'm trying to stay away from MySQL for this, which is another reason I think that this is the best method. I'm just stumped on the login/saving parts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question?

Comment: You can't really stay away from MySQL, or at least some sort of database, for this because otherwise where is the edited content going to be stored?  Content editable only lets you edit pages in the browser, it doesn't send those changes to the server, you'd have to do that yourself.  WordPress or a similar CMS might be overkill, but it would work and you wouldn't have to worry about the security implications of rolling your own.

Comment: @robertc You can stay away from MySQL, because that's a relational database. You can still use PHP and file storage, because that's not prohibited by the questioner.

Comment: @RandyMarsh File storage would still be 'some sort of database' and the security implications of getting it wrong would be even more fun.

Answer (score 2):

Still in beta though.

http://selectorapp.net/

Uses ftp as login.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to find something similar for my own projects. I just found [Runty](http://runtyapp.org/), which looks like it suits your needs.

It uses PHP and Javascript with HTML5 contenteditable. Basically you just embed a PHP script in your page and define editable areas by setting the `runty-editable` CSS class for HTML elements. Then login to http://yoursite.com/runty .

It looks like the project hasn't been updated in a few months though, and I still need to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

http://mojomotor.com/

Needs a database though and not free

Or similar and free, very basic CMS

http://get-simple.info/

Answer (score 0):

Someone already mentioned it (while it was still in beta), but checkout: [selector.io](https://selector.io)

This will handle all of your concerns:

1. Provides a login interface for users
2. Nice editor so users can easily make changes, try it here: [selector.io/demo](http://selector.io/demo)
3. Saves changes back to your server’s HTML files (nothing is installed on your server)

Minimal setup, plus it can be used on highly interactive and animated sites.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a very old question, but I built something for a very similar purpose last month. It's completely client side and very light.

It's an extension for Chrome that let's you use `contenteditable` as a CMS, similar to the way you described what you wanted.

You need to include a single Javascript file on the page you want to make "pedit enabled "  and add a `data-pedit` attribute to elements in that page that should be editable.

After that, while viewing your site in Chrome, you can login by opening the extension (the first time you do it it'll ask you to setup a password) and to start editing your individual contenteditable tags. When you hit the extension icon again, it'll save all your changes.

Check it out at http://pedit.xyz